# mvc dataconnection passing data in datatable format display

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = obj_Data.selData();
                if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
                {
                        string [,] arr1=new string[dt.Columns.Count+1,dt.Rows.Count+1];
                        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                            {
                                arr1[i,j] = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                            return View(arr1);
                    }
                }


            return View();
```

I'm jest passing data search result into data table format on to controller ,how can i display this data o view??

Comment: You're going to need to clarify your question...